# ¿Cómo obtener los datos del cliente en una factura?

Tags: c#, ddd

Estoy empezando a mirar cómo diseñar en DDD y estaba pensando en un caso sencillo. Se trata de una factura y el cliente.

Si alguna suposición que haga es incorrecta, agradecería que se corrigiera para ir aprendiendo un poco más.

En este caso considero que tanto la factura como el cliente son agregaciones raíz.

Se tiene que saber de quién es la factura, por lo que la factura debe tener una relación con el cliente. Según he leído, entidades root no pueden tener una referencia a un objeto de tipo de otra agregación raíz, solo referencias a instancias de elementos internos de su agregación. Que la forma de refernciar en estos casos es teniendo una propiedad con el ID de la otra entidad raíz. Por tanto se tendría la siguiente entidad factura:

```
public class Factura
{
    long Id {get; private set; }
    string Concepto {get; private set;}

    //otros  campos de la factura

    long IdCliente {get; private set;}
}
```

Hasta aquí bien, pero mi duda es la siguiente. En el momento en que necesita consultar la información del cliente de una factura, ¿cómo lo hago si solo tengo acceso al ID? ¿Necesito un servicio que primero obtenga la información de la factura mediante una consulta a la base de datos y luego realizar otra consulta para obtener la información del cliente?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te podría responder en términos de Entity Framework, pero parece que a ti te interesa la solución usando el patrón DDD, o me equivoco?

Comment: Sí, eso es. En entity framework sabría con el include, es sencillo. Yo me refería más a DDD, porque cambia un poco. Realmente he trabajado más con EF y al empezar a interesarme en DDD, hay cosas que cambian, como esta, por lo que cambia un poco la forma de plantearlo.

Comment: Según lo que entiendo es que Cliente es root, pero Factura no lo es.  Una factura puede existir sin un cliente?? no. Un cliente puede existir sin facturas?? si. Teniendo eso en cuenta creo que se desenreda tu situación

Comment: No estoy seguro de ello. En este link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/microservice-domain-model se puede ver cómo comprador y orden son dos agregaciones. Y tanto comprador como orden son entidades raíz. Esto se puede extrapolar a cliente y factura en mi caso. Ambos son entidades raíz y agrecaciones diferentes.